# Sum powers to n

Tags: code-golf, sequence, number-theory

Each natural number (including 0) can be written as a sum of distinct powers of integers (with a minimum exponent of 2).  Your task is to output the smallest power required to represent \$n\$.

For example:

```js
2 = 1^2 + 1^3 // Output 3
9 = 1^2 + 2^3 = 3^2 // Output 2
15 = 2^2 + 2^3 + 1^4 + 1^5 + 1^6 // Output 6
20 = 2^2 + 0^3 + 2^4 // Output 4
```

Ungolfed slow reference implementation (js):

```js
function f(x){
    for (let maxPower = 2; true; maxPower++){
        let bases = Array(maxPower - 1).fill(0);
        let sum = 0;
        while (sum != x && bases[0] ** 2 <= x){
            sum = bases.reduce((a, c, i) => a + c ** (i + 2), 0);
            let nextIncr = bases.length - 1;
            do {
                if (nextIncr < bases.length - 1) bases[nextIncr + 1] = 0;
                bases[nextIncr]++;
            } while (nextIncr && bases[nextIncr] ** (nextIncr--) > x)
        }
        if (sum == x) return maxPower;
    }
}
```

This is a [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) challenge.  The sequence is naturally 0-indexed, so you may **not** 1-index it.  You may...

- Take a positive integer \$n\$ and output the first \$n\$ values.
- Take a positive integer \$n\$ and output the value for \$n\$.
- Take no input and output values indefinitely.

The sequence starts: `2,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,3,2,3,4,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5`

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

--

Honestly, I'm surprised this isn't on the OEIS.  I'm also uncertain whether there's any number above 6 in the sequence - not that I've searched that far.

Comment: Wait, so do the exponents have to increase by `1` each time? Or do they just have to be distinct?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms They just have to be distinct.  That being said, the two cases are equivalent because you can have `0^x` for all of the missing ones.

Comment: You might want to add an example where one is skipped, to make that clearer

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms Like `20 = 2^2 + 0^3 + 2^4 // Output 4`?  Like I said, the two cases are equivalent so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Numbers which are not of the form \$a^2+b^3+c^4+d^5\$ are listed in [A111151](https://oeis.org/A111151). (These are the 6's in your sequence.)

Comment: If this really isn't in OEIS, you should submit it! It'd be good for them to have, and good to have linked to this question once it is up :)

Comment: Can we use negative integers? e.g. 0 = 8² + (-4)³

Comment: I'm confused why `0^3` is included in the example for 20?  It doesn't seem required, since `2^2 + 2^4` would also be be a valid answer.

Comment: How do we know that `Each natural number (including 0) can be written as a sum of distinct powers of integers (with a minimum exponent of 2)`? It isn't obvious to me, and a quick Google search only yields theorems valid for large enough \$n\$.

Comment: @RobinRyder Only the exponents have to be distinct, so you can do \$n = \sum_{i=2}^{n+1} 1^i\$

Comment: @wastl Thanks! I had missed that we could reuse the base.

Answer (score 8):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 63 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,m=2,i=0,p=n-i**m)=>p<0?f(n,m+1):!p||i&&f(p)<m?m:f(n,m,i+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclLCoMwEADQq6QbmbExpC7FUXqOUkqwpkwxyRClUPDu6edt39O93Dpllq2J6T6X4gmiDtRqJquFYsN1HZAG6e3of3U8YXeQfeeq8iDYhzF0/9D8rTKluKZlNkt6wMUYc87ZvaG1eDXBCcBNK0ZFg/LAiFg@)

Time out for not so large n as its terrible recursion design. It could be fast if we apply memorize to it (70 bytes).

```js
f=(n,m=2,i=0,p=n-i**m)=>f[n]??=p<0?f(n,m+1):!p||i&&f(p)<m?m:f(n,m,i+1)

o.value = [...Array(50000)].map((_, i) => i).filter(v => f(v) > 5).join(', ')
```

```html
<a href="https://oeis.org/A111151">A111151</a>: <output id=o></output>
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 109 bytes

This could probably be a bit shorter, but I tried to make it fast. Prints the sequence indefinitely.

```python
a=[i:=1]
k=2
while[print(k),k:=2]:
 while all(k<=a[i-b**k]for b in range(1,1+int(i**(1/k)))):k+=1
 a+=k,;i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBCsMgEADvvmKPRg1l00ux2ZeIBwNps6wYkUDp603aOQ0DU7/Htpf7o7beEwX2hFEJTeqzcV5DbVwOLYMTT1P0Cv4ZUs5aZkqBx8UYia@9wQJcoKXyXjU6tL@PjdF4k@HCiyVUkCyJe/LlvZ8)

Comment: A trivial -2 bytes in Python 3.8: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBCsIwEEX3OcUs00lERzeSNicRF1OsdpiQhlAQTx8j/t17j18@@7rly7XU1pC9xJM371XSAhriORj4AwPnB3BKVqfINznMiHp/bhVmkAyV82ux5MlJ3q0gWjrq0BfURTJQ6s/rMLKLMlG/qR@lp9a@ "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") (although that means we can't use PyPy on TIO)

Comment: @pxeger thanks, I was able to save a few more bytes based on this, and it still floods the output fast enough

Comment: what exactly does `a=[i:=1]` do?

Comment: @Eumel `i:=1` is an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), which assign `i` the value 1 and returns 1. The entire thing is equivalent to `i=1;a=[i]`

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES7), 79 bytes

Returns the n-th term (0-indexed).

```javascript
f=(n,q=2)=>(g=(k,t=n,i=0)=>t?i>t|k<2||g(k-1,t-i**k)*g(k,t,i+1):0)(q)?f(n,q+1):q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBDoMgEEWvwsLFjGIDLltHr6KxSihmqEq6Ec9OZfdf8t7/jL/xmHb7DTX795zSQsByowapA0PgZCCWltTNobddiK5tYjTgai1DbcvSYWmyJm2l8akQNuyX/JFxS4vfgQUJ9RIsWhJa5VVVKCbPh1/nx@oNDCMUJ194i8V513gNmP4)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = (            // f is the outer recursive function taking:
  n,             //   n = input
  q = 2          //   q = upper bound for the exponent
) =>             //
(                //
  g = (          // g is the inner recursive function taking:
    k,           //   k = exponent
    t = n,       //   t = remainder
    i = 0        //   i = base
  ) =>           //
  t ?            //   if t is not equal to 0:
    i > t |      //     abort if i is greater than t
                 //     (this is slower but shorter than i ** k > t)
    k < 2 ||     //     or k = 1
    g(           //     otherwise, do a recursive call:
      k - 1,     //       decrement k
      t - i ** k //       subtract i ** k from t
    ) *          //     end of recursive call
    g(           //     do another recursive call:
      k,         //       leave k unchanged
      t,         //       leave t unchanged
      i + 1      //       increment i
    )            //     end of recursive call
  :              //   else:
    0            //     success: return 0
)(q)             // initial call with k = q
?                // if it failed:
  f(n, q + 1)    //   try again with q + 1
:                // else:
  q              //   success: return q
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

Very inefficient brute force approach. Prints \$a(n)\$ given \$n\$.

```
∞>.ΔIÝy<ãεā>mO}Iå
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9vc2FiaWX//@KInj4uzpRJw515PMOjzrXEgT5tT31Jw6X//zE1)

A more efficient recursive version that is similar to my Python answer is 23 bytes long:

```
λNU∞>.ΔXyzmLymXα₅ß›]Y0ǝ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9vc2FiaWX//867TlXiiJ4@Ls6UWHl6bUx5bVjOseKChcOf4oC6XVkwx53//w)

**Commented**:

```
∞>.ΔIÝy<ãεā>mO}Iå   -- Takes input n and prints a(n)
∞>                  -- infinite list [2, 3, 4, ...]
  .Δ                -- find the first value y in this list with:
    IÝ              --   range from 0 to the input n
      y<ã           --   cartesian power [0 .. n] ^ (y-1)
         ε    }     --   map over each (y-1)-tuple:
          ā>        --     range [2 .. length+1] = [2 .. y]
            m       --     exponentiation
             O      --     sum the values
               Iå   --   is the input in this list?

λNU∞>.ΔXyzmLymXα₅ß›]Y0ǝ -- takes no input and prints the infinite sequence
λ                   -- start recursive environment with a(0)=1
                    -- for each N in [1, 2, ...], calculate a(N) by:
 NU                 --   store N in variable X
   ∞>.Δ             --   find y in [2, 3, 4, ...] with:
        yz          --     1/y
       X  m         --     X ^ (1/y)
           L        --     [1..floor(X^(1/y))]
            ym      --     [1..floor(X^(1/y))]^y
              Xα    --     abs([1..floor(X^(1/y))]^y - X)
                ₅   --     a(abs([1..floor(X^(1/y))]^y - X))
                 ß› --     y > min(a(abs([1..floor(X^(1/y))]^y - X)))
Y0ǝ                 -- Set the value at index 0 to 2
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 18 bytes

```
λ›⁰ʀnÞẊƛż›e∑;?c;ṅ›
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLOu+KAuuKBsMqAbsOe4bqKxpvFvOKAumXiiJE7P2M74bmF4oC6IiwiIiwiMjAiXQ==)

Vyxal has become bugless at last.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>84</s> 74 bytes

```ruby
->n,*r{(2..n**n).find{|x|a=0;r=1;x/=n while x>0&&a+=(x%n)**r+=1;a==n}?r:2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5PR6uoWsNITy9PSytPUy8tMy@luqaiJtHWwLrI1tC6Qt82T6E8IzMnVaHCzkBNLVHbVqNCNU9TS6tIGyidaGubV2tfZGVU@79AIS3aMJYLRBlBKEsIZWgKFTWI/Q8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 30 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Åœ¬_æÙδì€`é.Δā>zδmœ€Å\1%_Pà}g>
```

Outputs the value for a *positive* input \$n\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AT4Awf9vc2FiaWX//8OFxZPCrF/Ot8KvxaHOtMOs4oKsYMOpLs6UxIE@es60bcWT4oKsw4VcMSVfUMOgfWc@//8yMA) or [verify the values in the range \$[1,25]\$](https://tio.run/##AUsAtP9vc2FiaWX/MjVFTj8iIOKGkiAiP07/w4XFk8KsX863wq/Foc60w6zigqxgw6kuzpTEgT56zrRtxZPigqzDhVwxJV9Qw6B9Zz7/LP8) (with `æÙ` replaced with `η¯š` to speed it up).

**Explanation:**

```python
Åœ                # Get all possible sum-lists that equal the (implicit) input
                  # Because these sums lack 0s, we add those as well:
  ¬               #  Head (without popping), which are an input amount of 1s
   _              #  Convert each to a 0
    æ             #  Get the powerset of this
     Ù            #  Uniquify this list
    η¯š           #  Sped-up alternative:
    η             #   Get the prefixes of this list
     ¯š           #   And prepend an additional empty list
       δ          #  Apply double-vectorized:
        ì         #   Prepend-merge the lists
         €`       #  Flatten the list of lists one level down
                  # (we've now added [0,input] amount of 0s to each sum of `Åœ`)
é                 # Sort this list of lists by length
 .Δ               # Find the first/shortest which is truthy for:
   ā              #  Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
    >             #  Increase each by 1 to make the range [2,length+1]
     z            #  Calculate 1/n for each: [1/2,1/3,...,1/(length+1)]
      δ           #  Apply double-vectorized:
       m          #   Exponentiation
                  #  Check if at least one of these lists uses each exponent in
                  #  the range [2,length+1]:
        œ         #   Get all permutations of this list of lists
         €        #   Map each permutation-matrix to:
          Å\      #    Pop and leave its main diagonal
            1%    #   Modulo-1 on each
              _   #   And check if its decimals are 0 (thus it's an integer)
               P  #   Product to check if this is truthy for all
                à #   Max to check if this is truthy for any main diagonal
  }g>             # When we've found our result: pop and push its length + 1
                  # (after which it is output implicitly as result)
```

[See this for a step-by-step output with added debug-lines.](https://tio.run/##VVJNa9tAEL3nVwyCnmq1UY6FxoSSQA8FQ45pSMfWWFqy2hX74cSGHlrIL2h/QHssGHoJ6d1Orv4R/SPqzMppnIukZd578/Y9WY9jRV2XvTdtDG8gG75d3Q33siOtobVeBTUjUCZQRc5DqDGAjw0Ey9/K82TLWt88fNsyyxLO9gdpcg7Y2GgC2Cnse2ERTmpREM5qebH5s/r98HNzu17@/br81AucWhdgPAdNpgp1Ev/VT06UKXkvwVQ5H@CqVizGLoKLoZ7D1Lokezd8tfm@lwGcxibXipG8eFLT5DLdTyaj6GtASENlkqZDUxGcHQz6vS@Lc0HffzlMhHfWzIh9Jf8sV7yeoY4kkEUCHF@31pAJGJQ1UNo41pTPaBKsUwsqBbi5bfrl5JrYA70kk5JMVvggby9ozlPAH5D9lQora1ALIDlonyQEy@Gtbz72RuWe22jQPXUnsOLFxQ5GbTc/CxCQi@eNaPhpyCU/wh09Z6KZwxU@MlNJP1JJn7MTbrwERz7qnR9qZFsmldBK8ip4eIx5sNOj1PCfVx0Ouq4oujw3Nte4mP8D)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>40</s> 39 bytes

```
ＦＮ⊞υ⊗¬ιＦ…²χＦ⮌⌕Ａυ⁰Ｆ⊙υΣ✂…υ⊕⁻κＸμι±¹§≔υκιＩυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7NCsIwEITvPkWOG4iggidPpSL0YCn2CWK6tsF0I/lR@/QxUY/7zczOqEk6ZaVJ6WYdg4YeMbRxvqIDzlkX/QRRsKONV4MDtDaA5pwfVl/3RdKIsBNsu8nmH8InOo9w0jRUxpRw1v5iRUsBfZyhN1oh1IsyWE/2UXBDyuGMFHLRWVP0cBess688ZRas1HLBWhxlQNiWi7PKez1SFRoa8F1@3IvxsOqcpgC19AFiXpvSbp/WT/MB) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first `n` values. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ⊞υ⊗¬ι
```

Start with `0` having been found to have a value of `2` but none of the other values having been found yet.

```
Ｆ…²χ
```

Try from squares up to ninth powers.

```
Ｆ⮌⌕Ａυ⁰
```

Loop over all of the values that haven't yet been found in reverse order, so the highest index is tested first.

```
Ｆ⊙υΣ✂…υ⊕⁻κＸμι±¹
```

Subtract the powers of all the integers up to `n` from the current index and see if any of those values had previously been found. This is harder than it sounds as it's necessary to defeat Charcoal's cyclic indexing.

```
§≔υκι
```

If so then mark this value with the necessary power.

```
Ｉυ
```

Output all of the values.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>91</s> 88 bytes

```r
f=function(n,m=2,o=n+3,a=n-(0:n)^m)`if`(m<o&&all(a),min(sapply(a[a>0],f,m+1,o)),m/(m<o))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3RCsIwDAD/ZiQsYqdvw/gjoi7ICoUmKetE/Po6wRef745bWlXJea7rvfhrXrhFjk97rMkNjJQP5Gz9kYRtB2E0vClOKU6gJ@@6LQVB0mRQpZT8BrnIOVwpkvYDOW5s/1UR208I4xDof4rtAw)

Outputs the value for `n`.  Very slow for even moderate `n`.

```r
f=function(n,        # recursive function with argument n
 m=2,                # m=power to use in this iteration
 o=n+3,              # o=maximum power: stop when m reaches this
 a=n-(0:n)^m         # a=array of values by subtracting 0..n raised to m-th power from n
 )
 `if`(m<o,...,Inf)   # if m is too big, stop
  `if`(all(a),...,m) # if there are any zero values in a, then we've got n: stop and return m
                     # otherwise:
   min(              # return the lowest value of
    sapply(a[a>0],f,m+1,o)
                     # recursive calls to f with all positive values of a, using power m+1
   )
```

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 79* bytes

(* assuming that there are no values above 6 in the sequence, as conjectured in the comment to A111151)

```r
f=function(n,m=2,a=n-(0:n)^m)`if`(m<7&all(a),min(sapply(a[a>0],f,m+1)),m/(m<7))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY3RCoMwDAD/ZiSYsSqMgaz@iGwahoVCE0uriF/fOdiLz3fHpZKFQ5jyMsR5m5ItzrpVP4ufFZTENsRWr2Baxbfg6N0I8nxcjgYYSbxC5hjDDtxzZ17kSKoaD3L7eYjlj017N3R@YfkC)

Also outputs the value for `n`, but somewhat more efficiently than the 91-byte code, as the recursion can stop much sooner.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 73 bytes

```
f n=head(filter((!)n)[2..])
n!m=n==0||(m>1&&any(\k->(n-k^m)!(m-1))[0..n])
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##FcqxCsMgEADQvV9xLuFuUEx28xMdEwtCFYPeNSSWUsi/W/rml8NZYq29JxCXY3hi2mqLB6IioWUyxtNNFDtxzl4X8jwOQ5AvrkXPKLo8mBSyHokWa4x46hw2AQf7u93bAXjm1weQww4J/mWynqj/AA)

f(n) returns the nth value in the sequence (0-indexed).  n!m calculates whether n can be expressed as the sum of m (or fewer) powers.